# CKEditor CTRL + Right Arrow while editing doesn't skip to end

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, ckeditor

While editing a text using CKEditor, I've encountered some wierd behaviour. When using CTRL + right arrow to skip to the next word the caret doesn't jump behind the last word on the end of the line. It acts like this only on Firefox, it's working normally on Chrome.

According to the information I've found on the internets the position of the caret when using CTRL + arrows should be as follows:

**CTRL + LEFT ARROW**

`|This |is |a |sample |sentence.`

**CTRL + RIGHT ARROW**

`This |is |a |sample |sentence.|`

But the positions I am getting when using CTRL + right arrow are

`This |is |a |sample |sentence.`

**Has anyone experienced this? Are there any workarounds? Is it a Firefox or CKEditor issue?**

I am using

`Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit`

`Google Chrome Version 42.0.2311.135 m`

`Mozilla Firefox 37.0.2`

`CKEditor 4.3.1`

Comment: I have similar problem. If I have sentence like this:

This is a sample sentence:
I would expect cursor jumps would be

|This |is |a |sample |sentence|:|

but now I get |This |is |a |sample |sentence:|

But the  main problem is, if that isn't the last sentence in document cursor doen't jump to position after ":" but it jumps to new line. Any idea about that?

Comment: Yeah that's quite similar.. I haven't found an answer yet :(

Comment: Did you maybe report a bug? If not, I will....

Comment: I haven't. I wasn't sure if it is a bug or if it's only on my side, because it's not mentioned a lot online. Would you be so kind and post a link to the ticket here in the comments, please?